# Symfony 2.3 production with web profiler resulting in blank page

Tags: symfony, config

Ok, before anyone shoots me down. I do not actually want to run the web profiler in prod mode.

I have just started leanring symfony from the symblog tutorial (which is excellent).

The latter part of section 5 discusses the different config files, dev and prod.

As a test I wanted to get the web profiler switched on in prod mode but when i enter the config settings to do so:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

then clear the cache,

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

i get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                         
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler" (in /var/webroot/www/vhosts/wizards.co.uk  
  /htdocs/Symfony/app/config/config_prod.yml). Looked for namespace "web_profiler", found "framework", "security",   
  "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "blogger_blog", "doctrine_migr  
  ations"
```

Is the web profiler made unavailable in production mode for idiots like me trying to mess around with it :)  ?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

And after hitting post I realised the logic in the AppKernal is doing just that:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }
```

Comment: I got the same problem as you. What did you do to fix your problem?

Comment: from memory, i believe you need to include the bundles mentioned above in the live conditional.. they are only included in the dev/test environment by default

Answer (score 0):

The webProfilerBundle is not included in the production environment, so that need to be done by adding it to the previous bundle array without any if condition.

```
 public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

Then clear the cache in the 'prod' environment

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

And now it should work!